# Odd behaviour of python's class

Tags: python, class, constructor, initialization

Here is a python class:

```
class TxdTest(object):
    def __init__(self, name = '', atrributes = []):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = atrributes
```

and then I use it like this:

```
def main():
    for i in range(3):
        test = TxdTest()
        print test.name
        print test.attributes
        test.name = 'a'
        test.attributes.append(1)
```

so, what's the result? The result is:

[]

[1]

[1, 1]

Why the 'self.attributes' in class still obtain the value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing a mutable object (like a list) to a function or method in python, a single object is used across all invocations of the function or method. This means that ever time that function or method (in this case, your `__init__` method) is called, the exact same list is used every time, holding on to modifications made previously.

If you want to have an empty list as a default, you should do the following:

```
class TxdTest(object):
    def __init__(self, name = '', atrributes = None):
        self.name = name
        if attributes is None
             self.attributes = []
        else:
             self.attributes = attributes
```

For a detailed explanation of how this works see: [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument), as mentioned by  bgporter.

Comment: @Sonny for brevity without loss of readability, consider the ternary operator `self.attributes = list() if attributes is None else attributes`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there's only one list, because it is assigned when the function is *defined* not when it's called. So all instances of the class use the same `attributes` list.

Nothing to do with classes; the problem occurs whenever you use a mutable object as a default value in a function argument list.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the "Python Pitfalls" described here: http://zephyrfalcon.org/labs/python_pitfalls.html

(You'll want #2 and #5. The article is from 2003, but it still applies to modern Python versions.)